# Counter in EditorTemplates ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I would like to display an incremental value in editor template.

My Razor View-

```
@model  List<Target>

<form>
    @Html.EditorForModel()  
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My Editor Template -

```
@model Target

<div>
   <p>SL No.: ?? </p>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity) 
</div>
```

My question is how can I increment a variable i.e. counter here?

Comment: Short answer is you cannot (unless your model contains a property which is for the number and you set it in the GET method)

Comment: You can use an Application variable